# Run script on Task Scheduler windows where an excel file is created

Tags: excel, windows-task-scheduler, rscript

I need help with that problem. Searching on Google, I've found a way to run the R script without error. It's creating a .bat file with the directorys of Rscript.exe and the script I want to run:

[image]

My script is very simple: create a dataframe and save it on a Excel.

```
library(xlsx)

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

write.xlsx(employ.data, 'prueba_r_excel.xlsx')

print('final script')
```

When I manually run the file, it works without problems and creates the Excel:

[image]

[image]

But when I put it on task scheduler of windows,

[image]

[image]

it seems that it does the whole script without problems (it shows the print) but it doesn't create the file for me. Someone knows what could be the problem? Do I have to give some kind of special permission  to creat new files from the task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

First I thought that Task Scheduler could not create new files, because I saw that the Task Scheduler doesn't have write permissions. But later I found the error, and that is that in the part of the path where the file is saved you have to put it entire.

The problem was that if I ran the R script manually, the Excel is created in that same folder, but when executing it from the Task Scheduler I also created it but in another folder (system32)